# Older SF novel, humans and aliens underwater, with living membrane structures; relationship between human male and alien female

Tags: story-identification, novel

Probably anywhere from 70's to early 90's as I read it somewhere in the mid 90's. I remember,  there were humans and aliens underwater. The living structures were membranes not typical hard body structures. I think there was a relationship between the human male and an alien female.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I'm not going to add this as an answer because I'm not particularly sure of it, but could this be [Leviathan's Deep](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2851703-leviathan-s-deep) ?

Comment: Did the aliens always address a person by their full names? If so it’s probably from the 70’s